# Android graphical layout representation error?

Tags: android, xml, layout

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Exception details are logged in `Window > Show View > Error Log`

**The following classes could not be found:**
- `RelativeLayout (Change to android.widget.RelativeLayout, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)`

Comment: can you post your code here..